# How can I view images from iPhoto in Finder?

Tags: finder, photos.app

On my MacBook, with 10.7.3, if I go to `~/Pictures/iPhotoLibrary`, no images show in the Finder, though it does say "size 4.01GB". If I double click on iPhotoLibrary, iPhoto opens up — is this the only way to view images and drag files, etc? Can't I view them in Finder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iPhoto (and Aperture) library is now a **package** — it's still a folder on disk, but in order to view its contents, you must explicitly choose File > Show Package Contents in Finder (or you can right-click on it).

[image]

Comment: Be aware, this isn't good practice since you're working with the original files!! Once you made a change in tha package content, you won't be able to return or revert it in any way...

Answer (score 1):

I found another way recently where by you can simply locate the file in finder itself. I have attached some step-by step photos of how to locate them but it essentially goes like so:

1. Open Finder
2. Go to 'Pictures'
3. Right-click 'iPhoto Library'
4. Select 'Show Package Contents'
5. You will be presented with several folders
6. Select 'Masters'
7. Within this are folders of every year photos have been taken in
   From here you can go to every event and date, however, in a rather unfortunately awkward way

Hopefully that helps if you are looking for another way, and more direct way, to locate files directly within finder, especially in you fancy renaming the once that you want or need.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]
[image: And you guessed it..Step 5]

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer helpful https://superuser.com/questions/186385/how-to-open-iphoto-library-folder-on-a-mac. Specifically "When you have an "open file" dialog (to choose files to upload, etc.) on the left there is also a media section which makes it convenient to access iPhoto photos. Pretty easy actually, no need to navigate through a package."[image]