# How can I locate in iPhoto an image selected in the Finder?

Tags: finder, applescript, photos.app

This is essentially the reverse of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46503/how-can-i-view-images-from-iphoto-in-finder): given that I have selected an image in the Finder, is there an applescript or similar tool which will open iPhoto and highlight this file in the library so I can delete/modify/tag/inspect it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic automator service that will allow you to select an image in Finder and then start the service to find it in iPhoto. It worked fine on my Snow Leopard machine.

HTH

[image: Automator Service Code]

[image: Launching Service]

EDIT:
Changed the code slightly to make it behave better and make it go into Edit mode. Here is the changed code. Open the Automator Service file, and copy/paste it over it. Save it and it should take effect immediately.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set fPath to POSIX path of (input as string)

    tell application "iPhoto"
        activate
        select album "PHOTOS"
        set photoList to every photo whose image path is fPath
        select item 1 of photoList

        # Pressing Enter key goes into Edit mode...
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Comment: When the iphoto library is collapsed the information bar says one picture is selected but it is not visible. Do you know how to extend the script to expand whatever album/event the picture is so it can be seen by the user?

Comment: See my edit. It that better?

Comment: Yes, that works if I replace the english word with the spanish version I have here. The film rolls are still collapsed, but I found out how to quickly open all at http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021004061050563 so it's not a problem any more.